# How to select only camera's across multiple scenes in bpy?

Tags: python, camera

How do I iterate and select only camera's across multiple scenes via python?
This is what I tried but only works for the first active scene.

```
import bpy
    
    objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
    scenes = bpy.data.scenes.keys()
    
    for i in scenes:
        bpy.context.window.scene = bpy.data.scenes[i]
        
        for obj in objects:
            obj.select_set(False)
            if obj.type == "CAMERA":
                obj.select_set(True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Always looping over context scene's objects.**

Logic error, you were only ever looping over the context scene's ("the first ones") objects.

Test code below, selects all and only camera objects.  Sets the scenes camera as active for each viewlayer.

```
import bpy
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    bpy.context.window.scene = scene
    for ob in scene.objects:
        ob.select_set(ob.type == 'CAMERA')
        # set scene camera to active for each viewlayer
        if scene.camera:
            for vl in scene.view_layers:
                vl.objects.active = scene.camera
```

Comment: Great thanks! Tried and it works, just curious - how does this de-select the other objects? Does `.select_set` deselect automatically?

Comment: Expression equates to true or false.

Comment: Ok, so true for camera's and false for other objects.